# Stuck In Low Graphics Mode - Nvidia/Intel - Recently moved and this is my only system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I admit fully I did a dumb thing and when trying to extend battery life. I followed the instructions in this article:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-ubuntu-16-04/

Nothing against the article but as soon as I restarted I was trapped in a loop of being in low graphics mode. I have tried reinstalling desktop, I have tried reinstalling drivers and removing drivers and am at a total loss.

Normally I would just fix it with a reinstall or something but I have recently moved to a new area and only brought a laptop....the broken laptop.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Regarding the reinstall: is the low graphics mode preventing you from downloading a new Ubuntu ISO and burning it? Even though I don't think it's really necessary to reinstall, you should be able to do it in case you want to.

Comment: It actually wouldn't even load beyond the warning but I ended up formatting the system. That being said I used the link you had attached before I posted but nothing came of it, that being said thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I only can add on a good advice: If you relay on a running system then make backup ! And take care that the backups can be restored. Therefor I use USB Thumb Flash-drives where the system is installed. They can easy be backuped simple with "dd" before running any funny patches/installations or trying things. This simple technique solved me a lot of headache cause I have alway a second copy of a good system already on a second stick. If I f...up something just swap the usb thumb. Other data will be on encrypted containers on the internal storage. data is simple backuped with rsync. it's simple and works for years now. Even in the data-center on "pro"-servers.